# Golang DB de-/serialization method (sqlx on top ofdatabase/sql)

Tags: database, go, serialization, struct, casting

I have a `Timestamp` column in the database and a struct with a type `int64` that should load the column as a integer timestamp.

Query:

```
select date from table;
```

Error:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "date": converting driver.Value type time.Time ("2019-04-14 21:49:59.159317 +0000 +0000") to a int64: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to define a serialization method on the struct instead of casting the timestamp to `int64` at the query level (`extract epoch...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom `int64` type so that you can then have it implement the `sql.Scanner` interface.

```
type Timestamp int64

func (ts *Timestamp) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case time.Time:
        *ts = Timestamp(v.Unix())
    case []byte:
        // ...
    case string:
        // ...
    }
    return nil
}
```

With this you can either use conversion when scanning the result:

```
type Record struct {
    Date int64
}

var r Record
if err := db.QueryRow("select data from table").Scan((*Timestamp)(&r.Date)); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Or you can change the field's type in the struct definition and then you can scan directly into the field:

```
type Record struct {
    Date Timestamp
}

var r Record
if err := db.QueryRow("select data from table").Scan(&r.Date); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```